# Passing php variable through html frameset url

Tags: php, html, html-frames

I have a php variable. I want to pass this variable through frameset url. I tried using different techniques ut no success so far. Can any one give me a tip? This is the example of my code and what I tried:

```
<?php $var = 2+3 ?>

   <frameset>
 <frame src="myurl.php?var = <?php echo $var ?>">   
  </frameset>
```

In the myurl.php, I included the following:

```
 $new_var = $_GET['var'];
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need `$` before var

```
 <?php $var = 2+3; ?>

   <frameset>
 <frame src="myurl.php?var=<?php echo $var; ?>">  
  </frameset>
```

Comment: I had tried it without $, I mistakenly included in my question. Any other suggestion?

Comment: You were right. There was something wrong with the declaration of `var`. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Remove the $ from the URL and it should work;

```
<frame src="myurl.php?var=<?php echo $var ?>">
```

Comment: view the source of the frameset, if there is no value are `var` then there is something wrong with your declaration of `var`

Comment: Uhm, it do work;

frame.php:
`<?php $var = 2+3; ?>
<frameset>
 <frame src="myurl.php?var=<?php echo $var ?>"> 
</frameset>`

myurl.php:
`<?php
 echo $_GET['var'];
`
Is working fine.